# Random from a list first trial

Tags: random, onload, getelementbyid

first question for me here!

I am trying to create a simple html random word selection from a list. This is where I am at, but there must be something very wrong.. any idea? 
Eventually I'd love to have those words on a simple page not in a popup alert.. But I am not too sure I can do that using onLoad.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Random from List</title>
<script>
var arrayIsme = ["troglodisme", "Asianisme", "Classicisme", "Dadaïsme", "lyrisme", "objectivisme"];
var randInt = randomGenerator(0, arrayIsme.length);
var item = array[randInt];
var textbox = document.getElementById("randomIsme").value = item;
function getValue(){
alert(x.innerHTML); }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1 id="randomIsme" onLoad="getValue()"> </h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Your example is wrong in a lot of aspects. 
For example, `randomGenerator` is not defined, and there is no variable as `array` (only `arrayIsme`).

Also, you cannot attach onload to a h1 tag. I suggest to read articles about the DOM and the Javascript execution model.

Your working example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Random from List</title>
      <script type="text/javascript">
       function getValue(){
           var arrayIsme = ["troglodisme", "Asianisme", "Classicisme", "Dadaïsme", "lyrisme", "objectivisme"];
           var randInt = ~~(Math.random() * arrayIsme.length); // calculating the random position in the array
           var item = arrayIsme[randInt];
           var textbox = document.getElementById("randomIsme").innerHTML = item; // we have to set innerHTML, not value
       }
       window.onload = getValue;
       </script>
   </head>
   <body>
       <h1 id="randomIsme"> </h1>
   </body>
</html>
```